# Chrome 71 AudioContext resuming with Twilio Client

Tags: twilio

With the Chrome 71 changes that start audiocontext's in a suspended state, we need to resume the audio context after a user interaction. We are handling this by displaying a red banner at the top of our website saying we need you to grant us permission to enable calling with a button. The button meets the user engagement so we can resume the audio context.

The issue I am having is that the device which I have already called `device.setup()` on does not have the `audioContext` available when the user clicks the button.

I should be able to access the audioContext through `device.audio.audioContext` and call the `resume()` method on it, but what I get instead is `undefined`.

Currently as a workaround I am calling `device.audio._audioContext.resume()`  and this is never undefined and works. But it seems to me like there is some bug where the public accessor for `audioContext` is not being defined in the twilio-client library. Or am I doing something wrong here?

In the es5 compiled code I see the following in the `device.js` file I see

```
Object.defineProperty(Device, "audioContext", {
    /**
     * The AudioContext to be used by {@link Device} instances.
     */
    get: function () {
        return Device._audioContext;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

I get undefined when calling this. However, the `device.audio` property is set in this bit of code, where it passes `Device.audioContext` as an option:

```
    this.audio = new (this.options.AudioHelper || AudioHelper) 
      (this._updateSinkIds, this._updateInputStream, getUserMedia, {
        audioContext: Device.audioContext,
        enabledSounds: this._enabledSounds,
        logEnabled: !!this.options.debug,
        logWarnings: !!this.options.warnings,
    });
```

And then in the `audiohelper.js` file the constructor calls:

```
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      _audioContext: {
        value: audioContext
      },
      // more stuff
    },
```

so it seems like when the `device` is initially created the `Device.audioContext` is in existence and is passed through to `audio._audioContext`, but later `Device.audioContext` loses its reference to the audio context.

Comment: Hey Ryan, is this the latest version of Twilio Client JS?

Comment: sorry forgot to include that, it is version 1.6.5 which is currently the latest

Comment: @philnash just a quick ping, not sure if you got a notification about my previous comment, if you need any more info please let me know!

Comment: I have raised this with the client team, but haven't heard back I'm afraid. I will follow up again. In the meantime, I understand you have a workaround, but would it not be better to set up your `Device` object when the user clicks rather than resuming the audio context?

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks for the reply. The workaround works for now, basically just getting access to the suspended audio context from a private (_ prefixed) accessor. We want to activate the audio context as soon as the user goes to our website because they could receive incoming calls and we don't want the incoming call audio to be muted. We could, as soon as they login, display some overlay like "ready to call" but is just so strange from a UI/UX perspective.

Comment: @philnash continuing from previous comment. Our current system assumes the user is meeting the heuristic for Chrome, because in most cases they will go to the site often enough that it will work, but if they login from another computer/browser or enough time elapses they could lose that, so when we try to start the `Device` and notice the context is suspended, we display a banner at the top of the app asking for their permission to enable call permissions. The button does nothing except meet the heuristic so we can resume the audio context.

Comment: Thanks for the full story Ryan. The client team is in the US and it's a public holiday today, but hopefully I will get a response from them soon and get back to you.

Comment: Oh man! I didn't even think about how I am pinging you on a Sunday on a holiday weekend, thanks so much for your help and time working with me on this! Twilio has an awesome team.

Comment: No worries, it's Monday for me at least now anyway!  Just want to make sure this gets sorted for you as I'm sure you're not the only one with the issue.

Comment: Would you be able to share the code you are using that fails when you call on `Device.audioContext`?

Comment: here is a sample gist of what I am doing that is relevant https://gist.github.com/audiolion/0a866b11c182092f578f0ece98018367

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This may be a failure of documentation or communication, but I think I know what is going on now.

`Device.audioContext` is a public method on the `Device` class. As you discovered in the code it is defined here:

```
Object.defineProperty(Device, "audioContext", {
    /**
     * The AudioContext to be used by {@link Device} instances.
     */
    get: function () {
        return Device._audioContext;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Note that this defines the `audioContext` property on the `Device` object itself.

But there is no definition for `audioContext` on instances of `Device`. This is why your code in the gist you posted fails when you try to call `state.device.audioContext`.

As you point out, the `audio` object on the `device` object is created using `Device.audioContext`. So, you can actually drop using the pseudo-private `device.audio._audioContext` and just use the public `Device.audioContext` when you want to `resume()`.

I would rewrite to:

```
resumeTwilioDevice = async () => {
  Twilio.Device.audioContext.resume();
};
```

Comment: Awesome, I will test this out today and get back to you

Comment: Forgot to reply back here @philnash all was good using the way you recommended. Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: Hey Ryan, glad that it does now work as intended! Would you be able to mark the answer as correct so that others can see it worked too? Thanks!